# what rule has coefficients to follow for an IIR filter to be stable?

Tags: filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

I'd like to play with IIR filters, but not by designing them with algorithm but rather play with the coefficients directly.
i got a stability problem though, because of course IIR filters are sensitive to design, and we have to make sure the filter is stable and will not go to infinity.
So is there a rule that have to follow coefficients that would automatically make the filter stable ? (the sum or product of coefficients, etc)

especially for all pole filters if possible ?

thanks so much

Jeff

Comment: Well, if you introduce more rules to your "IIR playing", then you're just increasing the quality of your algorithm ;)

Comment: anyway, **plenty** of questions here asking about [tag:infinite-impulse-response] and stability. You can look up all you'd need to know.

Comment: I think Jurik is only for FIR filters ? I need something for IIR and for all-poles more particularly, but thanks anyway

Comment: Ok stability doesn't concern non-regressive coefficients. that's exactly what i need (all pole is all regressive)